# How to save data to an array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to store every click event to an array in Mongoose and if there is no any array then it will create one for me. 
At the moment it simply saves as object i.e. {x: 954, y: 256}, {x: 254, y: 156}
What I need is something like this [{x: 954, y: 256}, {x: 254, y: 156}]

Here is my code:

clickModel Schema

```
enter code var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var integerValidator = require('mongoose-integer');
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

var clickPoint = new Schema({
    x: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    y: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    value: {
        type: Number,
        integer: true
    }
});

clickPoint.plugin(integerValidator);

//export model...
module.exports = mongoose.model("ClickPoint", clickPoint);
```

and here is the Controller that saves the data

```
var ClickPoint = require('../Models/point');

exports.addPoint = function (click) {
    var entry = new ClickPoint({
        x: click.x,
        y: click.y,
        value: click.value
    });

    entry.save();
};
```

Then I call this addPoint function from app.js

```
var clickPoint = require('./controllers/clickPoint.controller');

app.post('/clickPoint', function (req, res) {
    clickPoint.addPoint(req.body);
});
```

If you have any suggestions feel free offer them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the Schema as follows -

```
var clickPoint = new Schema({
  clicks: [
    x: {
      type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    y: {
      type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    value: {
      type: Number,
      integer: true
    }
  ]
});
```

Update the save functions

```
ClickPoint.findOne(function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    if (data) {
      data.clicks.push({
        x: click.x,
        y: click.y,
        value: click.value
      })
      data.save();

    } else {
      new ClickPoint({
        clicks: [{
          x: click.x,
          y: click.y,
          value: click.value
        }]
      });

      entry.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Suggestion - Store the Clicks based on user session or use some identifier to distinguish the client

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now as expected. Could you tell me please what you mean "based on user session"? To group the data in database by sessions or by login details?